Anime, I watched around 2010 - 2015 - Armored guy using shells inside his armor to manifest power to kill demons
I don't know if it's animation or anime but I kind of remember that the art was more like anime.
There was an armored guy who had a big truck and his armory in the back of truck. He would suit up in his armor but before suiting up he had a girl to help him mark up his body for the suit.
His suit had something like large shotgun shells on both his shoulders that he would use to manifest power (arc or plasma) into his gun to kill demons and if the shells ran out, he would die or something.

Shells like artillery shells? Sea shells? Or is that meant to be energy cells, like batteries?

more like shotgun shells but big ones. and If I remember correctly he had 3 on each arm.

If someone posts the correct answer, you can click on the checkmark to accept it, as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers are an excellent chance to [edit] further remembered details into your question, e.g. "I know it can't be Bullet La Demon because the armor style looked more like an armadillo's shell, and the demons all looked like catgirls with metal bits coming out of their spines."

Might be Strait Jacket

Strait Jacket is set an alternate history where magic was proven to exist in the year 1899. The use of sorcery spread throughout all facets of society and changed the social and technological development of the world. The location is Tristan, an urban metropolis that appears to be an amalgamation of turn-of-the-20th-century Tokyo, San Francisco, and Victorian-era London.

....

... These Sorcerist agents wear a suit of armor that resists the negative transforming effects of magic. These suits are referred to as "Mold Armor", or more commonly a "straitjacket", due to the fact they constrain human beings in their natural form. The Sorcerists also use magically tainted bullets from large hand-carried railguns powered by a combination of steam and magic, which are the only weapons capable of effectively stopping the magically transformed monsters.

You can see the Steinberg being drawn on before he is enclosed in his armor in the trailer.
Trailer



However, I haven't seen where he has shells on his arms yet.
Found with a search for anime where man fights demons with armored suit and guns

correct correct it's this anime thank you so much you saved me XD.

how did you find it ?

I edited my search terms into the answer. :) Not my first terms... but they're the ones who got me there.

thanks a lot, if you had time watch it later it's a good anime, I wasn't sure where the shells are located but they get ejected like shotgun shells and they give him the power to summon those 3 circles in front of his gun to shoot a powerful magic shot.

@AbolfazlMohammadnhzad If you liked the answer, you can further support it by upvoting it. It's above the green checkmark button.
